# How to do parallel processing with rowwise

Tags: r, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, tidyverse, rowwise

I am using `rowwise` to perform a function on each row. This takes a long time. In order to speed things up, is there a way to use parallel processing so that multiple cores are working on different rows concurrently?

As an example, I am aggregating PRISM weather data (https://prism.oregonstate.edu/) to the state level while weighting by population. This is based on https://www.patrickbaylis.com/blog/2021-08-15-pop-weighted-weather/.

Note that the below code requires downloads of daily weather data as well as the shapefile with population estimates at a very small geography.

```
library(prism)
library(tidyverse) 
library(sf)
library(exactextractr)
library(tigris)
library(terra)
library(raster)
library(ggthemes)

################################################################################
#get daily PRISM data
prism_set_dl_dir("/prism/daily/")
get_prism_dailys(type = "tmean", minDate = "2012-01-01", maxDate = "2021-07-31", keepZip=FALSE) 

Get states shape file and limit to lower 48    
states = tigris::states(cb = TRUE, resolution = "20m") %>%
    filter(!NAME %in% c("Alaska", "Hawaii", "Puerto Rico"))

setwd("/prism/daily")

################################################################################
#get list of files in the directory, and extract date
##see if it is stable (TRUE) or provisional data (FALSE)
list <- ls_prism_data(name=TRUE) %>% mutate(date1=substr(files, nchar(files)-11, nchar(files)-4), 
            date2=substr(product_name, 1, 11),
            year = substr(date2, 8, 11), month=substr(date2, 1, 3), 
            month2=substr(date1, 5, 6), day=substr(date2, 5, 6),
            stable = str_detect(files, "stable"))

################################################################################
#function to get population weighted weather by state

#run the population raster outside of the loop
# SOURCE: https://sedac.ciesin.columbia.edu/data/set/usgrid-summary-file1-2000/data-download - Census 2000, population counts for continental US
pop_rast = raster("/population/usgrid_data_2000/geotiff/uspop00.tif")
pop_crop = crop(pop_rast, states)

states = tigris::states(cb = TRUE, resolution = "20m") %>%
    filter(!NAME %in% c("Alaska", "Hawaii", "Puerto Rico"))

daily_weather <- function(varname, filename, date) {
    weather_rast = raster(paste0(filename, "/", filename, ".bil"))
    
    weather_crop = crop(weather_rast, states)
    
    pop_rs = raster::resample(pop_crop, weather_crop)
    
    states$value <- exact_extract(weather_crop, states, fun = "weighted_mean", weights=pop_rs)
    names(states)[11] <- varname
    
    states <- data.frame(states) %>% arrange(NAME) %>% dplyr::select(c(6,11))
    states
}

################################################################################
days <- list %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(states = list(daily_weather("tmean", files, date1))))
```

As is, each row takes about 7 seconds. This adds up with 3500 rows. And I want to get other variables beside tmean. So it will take a day or more to do everything unless I can speed it up.

I am mainly interested in solutions to be able to use parallel processing with rowwise, but I also welcome other suggestions of how to speed up the code in other ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try either `purrr` of its multiprocessed equivalent `furrr` (either `map()` or `pmap()`). The quickest method would be to use `data.table`. See [this](https://www.brodrigues.co/blog/2021-09-05-speedrunning_rows/) blog post that gives some benchmarks behind my recommendation

Comment: A minor, but important correction: it's 'multiprocessed' - not 'multithreaded'.  There are important differences between threads and processes, e.g. threads can write to the same memory/objects, but processes does not.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [multidplyr](https://multidplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/multidplyr.html). The example in the documentation uses `group_by`, but it works the same way with `rowwise`.